# Declare multiple middle-wares in Express.js and in Node.js to call different routes

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I am new to nodeJs how to declare multiple middle-wares in expressJs and in node to call different routes like /state ,/contact.

```
routes.js
var routes;
  routes = (app) => {
    app.route('/contact')
    .get((req, res ,next) =>{
    // middleware
     console.log(`Request from: ${req.originalUrl}`)
      console.log(`Request type: ${req.method}`)
      next();
},getContacts)
  .post(addNewContact);
  app.route('/contact/:contactId')
    //get specific contact
    .get(getContactWithID)
     //put request
    .put(updateContact)
    .delete(deleteContact);
}
module.exports =router;
 routes = (app) => {
    app.route('/state')
    .get((req, res ,next) =>{

},getState)

}
module.exports =router
```

How to write code for middle wares to call different types of Url encoded statement example /state or /contact or /homepage 
how to declare these middle ware to get different request and response from URL and also perform to call all HTTP verbs methods.

Comment: formatting, shorting title and adding tags

Answer (score 0):

From the above I assume that you have a separate file for each task, and one of the is routing, which you've called `router.js`

**So short answer**, all what you need is the url library which is aready included in node.js:

```
var url = require("url");
```

This library allows for you to compare and get the url. For the full documentation visit: https://nodejs.org/api/url.html

But for now, to get the pathname of a certain url request, you use this code (in your middleware):

```
var pathname = url.parse(req.url).pathname;
```

This stores the pathanme of the request's url, for e.g: `/home`

---

**and a longer answer**, would be to answer the question of what you do with this pathname. Routing has several different ways in Node.js, but since there isn't much in the documentation, I'm going to say there is no set way of doing this. So how you want to do it depends on different things:

### How do you use the pathname to redirect to a certain part of your server?

Request Handlers. They take a pathname, and decide which code to execute based on it. There are 2 ways to do this. The first is to use `if statements`:

```
if (pathname == "/home"){
    res.writeHead(200,{"Content-Type" : "text/plain"]);
    res.end("This is the home page");
}
else if (pathname == "/contact"){
    res.writeHead(200,{"Content-Type" : "text/plain"});
    res.end("This is the contact page");
}
else{
    res.writeHead(200,{"Content-Type" : "text/plain"});
    res.end("This request is invalid");
}
```

Te code above is clear and obvious. However, many people regard it as "ugly", and they do have a point. Imagine your server grows and grows and you could have thousands of different pages for your server, this code could be huge! Not only will this make your code unreadable and unnecessarily huge, but it will also slow down the performance of your server, which can be an issue if you get thousands of requests to handle.

So this can be solved by creating an object called let's say... "handle". Each property of this object will contain different functions that were previously defined. The properties will be called the exact same as the pathname the user will have in the url.

```
//Pre defined functions that write stuff to the browser
function home(){
    res.writeHead(200,{"Content-Type" : "text/plain"});
    res.end("This is the home page");
}
function contact(){
    res.writeHead(200,{"Content-Type" : "text/plain"});
    res.end("This is the contact page");
}

//Create a handler object containing each of these functions
handle = []
handle["/"] = home;
handle["/home"] = home;
handle["/contact"] = contact;

handle[pathname]()
```

Any valid pathname is going to be the same as the name of one of the properties of handle object, so if we place the pathname were you would usually have the property of object, it's the same thing!

Although this is not necessary, you might also want to have this code in a separate code called `requestHandlers.js` to keep your code simple and clean.

Finally please note that this is a very basic answer, and doesn't deal with things like invalid url requests and separating code into neat files. I.E: your server will close if an invalid pathname is used in the browser. For a full answer you can check out [Node Beginner tutorial style pdf](http://www.hylianux.com/downloads/nodebeginner.pdf) by [Manuel Kiessling](https://leanpub.com/u/manuelkiessling)